# Socrata query length issue

Tags: query-string, socrata

I am developing a MVC Web app with socrata private dataset as my backend.
I am having some issues while passing more filters in the querystring to fetch data from socrata.

my soql is

```
resource/xxxx-xxxx.json?$select=pais_extendido,var_descripcion,rango_edad,genero,zona_geografica,tam_de_firma,quintil_ingreso_laboral,quintil_ingreso_total,anio2,tipo_variable,valor&$where=pais_extendido ='Bolivia' AND (var_descripcion ='Personas+que+no+estudian+ni+trabajan+(en+%25)' OR var_descripcion ='Personas+que+no+estudian+ni+trabajan+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='A%c3%b1os+de+educaci%c3%b3n+promedio' OR var_descripcion ='Personas+con+educaci%c3%b3n+terciaria+t%c3%a9cnica+(en+%25)' OR var_descripcion ='Personas+con+educaci%c3%b3n+terciaria+t%c3%a9cnica+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Poblaci%c3%b3n+ind%c3%adgena+o+afro-descendiente+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Poblaci%c3%b3n+ind%c3%adgena+or+afro-descendiente+(en+%25)' OR var_descripcion ='Poblaci%c3%b3n+total' OR var_descripcion ='Poblaci%c3%b3n+en+edad+de+trabajar+(en+%25)' OR var_descripcion ='Poblaci%c3%b3n+en+edad+de+trabajar+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Indicador+de+pobreza+(50%25promedio%2c+2011PPP%2c+escala+antigua+OCDE)' OR var_descripcion ='Indicador+de+pobreza+(60%25promedio%2c+2011PPP%2c+escala+antigua+OCDE)' OR var_descripcion ='Indicador+de+pobreza+extrema+(USD+2.5%2c+2011PPP)' OR var_descripcion ='Indicador+de+pobreza+extrema+(USD+2.5%2c+2011PPP%2c+escala+antigua+OCDE)' OR var_descripcion ='Indicador+de+pobreza+moderada+(USD+4%2c+2011PPP)' OR var_descripcion ='Indicador+de+pobreza+moderada+(USD+4%2c+2011PPP%2c+escala+antigua+OCDE)' OR var_descripcion ='Indicador+de+clase+alta+(USD+50%2b%2c+2011PPP)' OR var_descripcion ='Indicador+de+clase+media+(USD+10-50%2c+2011PPP)' OR var_descripcion ='Indicador+de+poblaci%c3%b3n+vulnerable+(USD+4-10%2c+2011PPP)' OR var_descripcion ='Formalidad+(1)%3a+Trabajadores+activos+cotizantes+a+la+seguridad+social+(en+%25+de+la+poblaci%c3%b3n+econ%c3%b3micamente+activa)' OR var_descripcion ='Formalidad+(1)%3a+Trabajadores+activos+cotizantes+a+la+seguridad+social+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Formalidad+(2)%3a+Ocupados+cotizantes+a+la+seguridad+social+(en+%25+de+la+poblaci%c3%b3n+ocupada)' OR var_descripcion ='Formalidad+(2)%3a+Ocupados+cotizantes+a+la+seguridad+social+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Formalidad+(3)%3a+Asalariados+cotizantes+a+la+seguridad+social+(en+%25+del+total+de+asalariados)' OR var_descripcion ='Formalidad+(3)%3a+Asalariados+cotizantes+a+la+seguridad+social+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Formalidad+(4)%3a+Trabajadores+independientes+cotizantes+a+la+seguridad+social+(en+%25+del+total+de+trabajadores+independientes)' OR var_descripcion ='Formalidad+(4)%3a+Trabajadores+independientes+cotizantes+a+la+seguridad+social+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Personas+de+65+o+m%c3%a1s+a%c3%b1os+que+declara+un+monto+recibido+por+pensi%c3%b3n+contributiva+(en+%25)' OR var_descripcion ='Personas+de+65+o+m%c3%a1s+a%c3%b1os+que+declara+un+monto+recibido+por+pensi%c3%b3n+contributiva+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Personas+de+65+o+m%c3%a1s+a%c3%b1os+que+declara+un+monto+recibido+por+pensi%c3%b3n+no+contributiva+(en+%25)' OR var_descripcion ='Personas+de+65+o+m%c3%a1s+a%c3%b1os+que+declara+un+monto+recibido+por+pensi%c3%b3n+no+contributiva+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Personas+de+65+o+m%c3%a1s+a%c3%b1os+que+declara+un+monto+recibido+por+pension+contributiva+o+no+contributiva+(en+%25)' OR var_descripcion ='Personas+de+65+o+m%c3%a1s+a%c3%b1os+que+declara+un+monto+recibido+por+pension+contributiva+o+no+contributiva+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Personas+de+65+o+m%c3%a1s+a%c3%b1os+que+trabaja+y+recibe+pensi%c3%b3n+(en+%25)' OR var_descripcion ='Personas+de+65+o+m%c3%a1s+a%c3%b1os+que+trabaja+y+recibe+pensi%c3%b3n+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Desempleados+aspirantes+(en+%25)' OR var_descripcion ='Desempleados+aspirantes+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Desempleados+cesantes+(en+%25)' OR var_descripcion ='Desempleados+cesantes+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Desempleados+de+larga+duraci%c3%b3n+(en+%25)' OR var_descripcion ='Desempleados+de+larga+duraci%c3%b3n+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Desocupados+con+educaci%c3%b3n+terciaria+t%c3%a9cnica+(en+%25)' OR var_descripcion ='Desocupados+con+educaci%c3%b3n+terciaria+t%c3%a9cnica+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Personas+que+no+estudian+ni+trabajan+ni+buscan+trabajo+(en+%25)' OR var_descripcion ='Personas+que+no+estudian+ni+trabajan+ni+buscan+trabajo+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Poblaci%c3%b3n+desocupada+(en+%25)' OR var_descripcion ='Poblaci%c3%b3n+desocupada+(en+niveles)' OR var_descripcion ='Promedio+de+duraci%c3%b3n+en+el+desempleo+(en+meses)') AND rango_edad ='Edad+15+a+64+a%c3%b1os' AND genero ='Ambos' AND zona_geografica ='Total' AND tam_de_firma ='No+aplica' AND quintil_ingreso_laboral ='Todos' AND quintil_ingreso_total ='Todos' AND (anio2 ='1990' OR anio2 ='1991' OR anio2 ='1992' OR anio2 ='1993' OR anio2 ='1994' OR anio2 ='1995' OR anio2 ='1996' OR anio2 ='1997' OR anio2 ='1998' OR anio2 ='1999' OR anio2 ='2000' OR anio2 ='2001' OR anio2 ='2002' OR anio2 ='2003' OR anio2 ='2004' OR anio2 ='2005' OR anio2 ='2006' OR anio2 ='2007' OR anio2 ='2008' OR anio2 ='2009' OR anio2 ='2010' OR anio2 ='2011' OR anio2 ='2012' OR anio2 ='2013' OR anio2 ='2014') AND tipo_variable ='niveles%2c+%23'&$limit=10000
```

I have tried the IN operator but since its is derived dataset its not working.
Can u help me optimize this query?

Is there any limitaion in the querystring length that should be send across browser or any limitations provided in the socrata end to limit the querystring length?

Comment: Can you share some more detail about what dataset you're accessing? Just a link to the dataset itself should be good to start with.

Comment: Is it possible to use web service like tinyurl to fetch the data from socrata. Please correct if  I am wrong!!!

Comment: URL shortening services use a redirect, so you'd still hit the maximum query string length specified by the HTTP spec, unfortunately that won't help here.